# Employer demanding "virtual police lineup" to identify employees who leaked salary info

Tags: united-states, ethics, canada, privacy, rights

I work with a team of engineers (remotely) in California (USA), and Quebec (Canada). Some people applied for various jobs at our company under false pretenses, i.e.:

- Attended the remote interviews.
- Did very well on the interview questions.
- Negotiated very high salaries for the associated pay grade.

It turns out these interviewees used face filters and voice filters to hide their real faces and voices during the interviews, and they posted interview summaries and salary information in a public location online (and e-mailed various company mailing lists with the results, plus some basis statistics such as male-versus-female salaries for the same job title). Management is beyond furious, and the work environment has become more toxic than usual (i.e. people are demanding raises and promotions, and citing the data). **Management suspects current employees were the perpetrators.**

My employer is now demanding several people (from both the USA and Canada offices) to read various lines from a script during a recorded video call. A friend in management disclosed that the legal department plans to run the videos through the voice/face filters they think were used, in order to "reverse match" (i.e. identify) who the people were that attended these staged/bad-faith interviews (so they can fire and sue them).

Can my employer demand this (in Canada or USA)? I'm a dual citizen, and work remotely, so I can just claim I currently reside in whichever location has better worker protections (probably Canada, is my guess).

I told my employer my web camera is broken, and they express-couriered me a replacement USB one almost overnight. I don't think I can keep "dropping" expensive web cams to delay for much longer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118110/discussion-on-question-by-hugo-employer-demanding-virtual-police-lineup-to-ide).

Answer (score 5):

**I am not a lawyer, I just found this same question posted to Reddit.**

This same question appeared on /r/legaladvicecanada and [you can find that discussion here.](https://old.reddit.com/r/legaladvicecanada/comments/kr924n/employer_demanding_virtual_police_lineup_to/)

What they seem to have decided is that while it is definitely legally fishy, they do not appear to have crossed the line quite yet but they are at least potentially close enough to make contacting a local employment lawyer worth it. There appear to be ways in which certain reactions on their part might violate employment law. But there isn't a clear cut answer.

Answer (score 3):

For more specific answer, you should consult with an employment lawyer.

But, IMHO, if employer is allowed to requested it, in case you decline, you can be fired.

Comment: Even if the employer is not actually allowed to make the request described, California is an at-will state so the author could still be fired, but what employment employee protections depends on the author's contract and Quebec  requirements on USA companies.  (circa not nearly enough information to determine anything).